# Error while trying to create first Sinatra extension

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm delving into Ruby and Sinatra for the first time, and running through Alan Harris and Konstatin Haase's "[Sinatra Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920019664.do)".  After sorting out my Ruby versions (using RVM), I haven't had any problems up to chapter 3, when creating an extension.  The code is as follows (post_get.rb):

```
require 'sinatra/base'

module Sinatra
  module PostGet
    def post_get (route, &block)
      get (route, &block)
      post (route, &block)
    end
  end

  register PostGet
end
```

Used with (post_get_test.rb):

```
require 'sinatra'
require './post_get'

post_get '/' do
        "Hello #{params[:names]}"
end
```

But, whenever I run "ruby post_get_test.rb" I get the following runtime error right away:

```
user@UbuntuOne:~/sinatra$ ruby post_get_test.rb 
/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': /home/user/sinatra/post_get.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
      get (route, &block)
                 ^
/home/user/sinatra/post_get.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
      post (route, &block)
                  ^
/home/user/sinatra/post_get.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from post_get_test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

I'm not quite sure even where to start in sorting this out. Can someone point me in the right direction to get this solved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you’ve posted is correct, but is different from the code reported in the error message.

In the error message the lines causing the error look like this:

```
get (route, &block)
```

and

```
post (route, &block)
```

Note the space between the `get` or `post` and the opening `(`. In Ruby when you call a method and you use parenthesis there mustn’t be a space between the method name and the opening parenthesis (like the code block in your question).

Make sure in your actual code there isn’t a space at this point and you should be okay.

What’s happening is Ruby is trying to parse what is contained in the parenthesis and pass the result as the *only* argument to the method, rather than using the contents of them as the list of arguments.

Comment: I was a bit sloppy when copying in that first code block, but I've edited it to show the correct white space.  I've changed the white space around a bit but nothing I've done seems to affect the error message I'm getting.

Comment: That was it.  I didn't realize that Ruby was sensitive to whitespace in that way.  Thanks.